# .NET Core project.json copyToOutput file in parent directory

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0, project.json

I need to include a file in my build output. This file is two folders above project.json. If I specify this using `"../../"`, the config file is copied over, but to the wrong location. Instead of being copied over to `/bin/Debug/net461`, it's placed two folders higher in `/bin`.

How do I get a file in a parent directory to be copied over to actual output folder where the dlls are placed?

```
"buildOptions": {
  "copyToOutput": { "includeFiles": [ "../../config.json" ] }
},
```

Comment: Your destination path is /bin/Debug/net461?

Comment: I guess it is by default because I don't set it anywhere. @mww

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try use this instead, it's tested way and working very well:

```
  "buildOptions": {
     "copyToOutput": "project.json",
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  }
```

You can use copy single file `"copyToOutput":"name"` or array `"copyToOutput":["name1","name2"]`. To copy directory need to use  `"copyToOutput":"name\\`"

Comment: Thank you! "copyToOutput":["../../name1","../../name2"] worked